# How to use Facebook SDK to do a FQL Query with graph API?

Tags: facebook

With this code:

```
string fqlQuery = string.Empty;
string sUIDList = string.Empty;

IDictionary<string, object> Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
FacebookApp fbApp = new FacebookApp();
fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic, profile_url FROM user WHERE uid IN (" + sUIList + ")"; 

Parameters.Add("method", "fql.query");
Parameters.Add("query", fqlQuery); 
var Info = (JsonArray)fbApp.Api(Parameters);
```

the method Api in the Facebook SDK uses the RestServer and not the Graph Api.
How can I do a FQL Query with Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you **can't**. We still need to use [`fql.query`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) to perform FQL actions.